# Change image path using .htaccess

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I want to change the image path (even stylesheet background image url) with  .htaccess, 
My Magento site gets all images from production site in local server,

Comment: Why dont you use core functionality System > Configuration > General / Web > Unsecure / Secure > Base Media URL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hello I have website1 is http://example1 and another is http://example2 If you want to change path using `.htaccess` the rule be

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^media/img/ http://www.example1.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC]
```